# accordion in ionic 2 showing irregular dispaly

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I wanted to use accordion in my ionic 2 app, I have edited one of [existing code](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/zYr1BB?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview) found on plunker as per my need.

I am unable to understand that why my things are not showing and hiding things correctly, [my plunker code](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1x1yKH9gm3jX4Lim).

updated code:

[updated](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/NuITNK5YHlc8zcjC), but still having issue of button, button is outside the loop, if I insert inside the loop, still having errors.